# Can IDEA generate componentN method in Kotlin

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

As http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#multi-declarations says:

> The component1() and component2() functions are another example of the principle of conventions widely used in Kotlin (see operators like + and *, for-loops etc.). Anything can be on the right-hand side of a destructuring declaration, as long as the required number of component functions can be called on it. And, of course, there can be component3() and component4() and so on.

For example,

```
class Pair<K, V>(val first: K, val second: V) {
    operator fun component1(): K {
        return first
    }

    operator fun component2(): V {
        return second
    }
}
```

But I think it's very boring to manually input these methods. So is there any way to generate these methods in `IDEA`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let IDEA help you. Take the following example, a simple class without `componentX` functions:

```
class Ex(val a: Int, val b: Int)
```

And then a destructuring of it, which does not compile:

```
val (a,b) = Ex(1,2)
```

IDEA will give you some hints on how to fix the problem if you use the shortcut ["Show intention action"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **data** classes.

In such case, you class should looks like:

```
data class Pair<K, V>(val first: K, val second: V)
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html